# Regex - Match String That Does Not Contain Only Spaces

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex expression that will return true if the string does not contain only spaces. My attempt so far is `^[^ \s]*$` but it does not pick up on strings that contains multiple words.

I want to be clear that I am trying to match a string that does not contain only spaces.

Test case:

```
'apple'                true
'apple banana'         true
'apple banana orange'  true
' apple banana'        true
'  apple banana'       true
' '                    false
'  '                   false
'   '                  false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might very well get along with:

```
^(?!\s+$).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/SkyrMV/2).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^         # start of the line / string
(?!\s+$)  # neg. lookahead, making sure there are not only whitespaces
.+        # at least one character, possibly more
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use `\S` to match non-space characters
- Allow spaces before and after a non-space

For example:

```
^\s*\S.*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a look ahead for a non-space:

```
^(?=.*\S).*
```

---

The good thing about look aheads is you can stack them up to combine unrelated assertions that might be hard to write as a straight regex. For example, suppose we wanted to add an assertion that there were no numbers:

```
^(?=.*\S)(?!.*\d).*
```

It would be awkward to write that as a simple regex, plus this is about as readable as regex gets - the look aheads are kept separate from each other and the main regex.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex to do that is:

```
\S
```

It will match any string that contains a non-whitespace character.